# CSS. Remove hover and click on :after

Tags: html, css, hover

I have this nav-bar!

```css
nav {
  // border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  list-style: outside none none;
  // list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  // padding: 10px;
  // padding-left: 0;
  margin: 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  // border: 1px solid black;
  // cursor:pointer;
  cursor: pointer;
  // progress: !important;

}
nav li:not(:last-child):after {
  content: '|';
  position: absolute;
  // display: inline-block;
  top: -1px;
  right: -18px;
  cursor: default;
}
li:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class='li'>Chisinau, MD</li>
    <li class='li'>Russia, RU</li>
    <li class='li'>London, UK</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

How to remove the hover and click function of that "vertical-slash"  on 
`:after`?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sthwvt0s/)

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/sthwvt0s/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove pointer-events by adding this:

```
nav li:not(:last-child):after {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

::after is a part of a li, so when you hover on ::after layer it is triggering li's hover. So you can just wrap li's content with span and change the hover to be triggered when you hover over span not li.

Like this.

```
<li class='li'><span>Chisinau, MD</span></li>
<li class='li'><span>Russia, RU</span></li>
<li class='li'><span>London, UK</span></li>
```

and CSS

```
li span:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);
}
```

To remove changing of cursor on | add

```
ul {
  cursor: default;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tdus7m3a/